# Different rules for class and template class?

Tags: c++

doesn't work with a normal class. The infamous

> error: field 's' has incomplete type 'S'

```
struct S
{
    struct N
    {
        S s;
    };
};

int main()
{
    S s;
}
```

Though why not? Doesn't make much sense. Why then the methods of `S` have a complete type. And methods of `N` have a complete type

```
struct S
{
    struct N
    {
        N(){ S s; }
    };
};

int main()
{
    S s;
}
```

and so the moment where it should work but doesn't, works with template classes

```
template<class=void>
struct S
{
    struct N
    {
        S s;
    };
};

int main()
{
    S<> s;
}
```

If it works with a template it should work with a normal class. Shouldn't it?

Comment: Note that a `S *` should work, though I can't properly articulate why.

Comment: Since the `S` definition is incomplete by the time you reference it, you can't do this. I'm at a loss as to why you'd want to here. Can't `N` be independent? If it's for namespacing purposes, put `N` and `S` on the same level and ideally declare `S` first.

Comment: "If it works with a template it should work with a normal class. Shouldn't it?" Uh, it depends. As noted below, classes and templates aren't the same. There are some differences in how they work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create an object of a class the compiler needs to know the size of the class. If the class isn't fully defined yet (which it isn't until the closing `}`) then the size is unknown, the compiler can't know if there's more members or not, and can thus not be able to create instance of the class.

A template isn't a class in itself, it's kind of like a blueprint for a class that will be defined sometime in the future. That's why templates can be nested, because it's only a *template* not an actual class. The class is known when the template is instantiated, which is it when you do e.g. `S<>`, and by then the compiler can use the template to create the actual class.

---

As noted pointers to classes works, because the size of a pointer is known.

Comment: Perhaps something like this is worth mentioning?
https://godbolt.org/z/FL4o81

Comment: now as I think about that, it makes sense. And any inline method would be inlined when the size is already known